# Where can I get a Red Soul Shard?

Tags: diablo-iii

I can't seem to find any tips on the Internet on how to get this gem. Everyone is showing the power of it, but not the location.

Does anyone know how to get it?

Answer (score 6):

From the [Red Soul Shard wikia page](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Red_Soul_Shard), it looks like this gem is *only* dropped by the Dark Lord himself as part of the yearly [Darkening of Tristram event](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Darkening_of_Tristram) (note: this event is new as of 2017):

> It can only be socketed into helms, and is obtained by completing the Darkening of Tristram event in January of each year. It drops from [Dark Lord](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Lord) ([Diablo](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Diablo_(Diablo_I))).

From the event page for the Darkening of Tristram, it looks like this is a **guaranteed** drop for completing the event dungeon:

> Completing the Dungeon also rewards a Legendary Gem, Red Soul Shard, that fits into the Helmet slot, reminiscent of Diablo's Soulstone (into which it will transmog the helmet).

Comment: It is worth noting that to get the transmog, you can put it into any helmet, equip it, then remove the gem. Then go back and socket the helmet with whatever you want.